# Pandas: creating column with groups based on difference in columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a column with period numbers (starting at 1) based on a difference in two columns. It should add 1 to the period number if Value1 != Value2. I have been able to create a subset of the rows where there is a difference between the two columns, but I would like to have the period numbers attached to the current df so I can do an analysis based on the group of periods.

I have been able to do this with a simple if-statement in Excel, but I hope there is a quicker solution using pandas.

I attached a basic code with the required output in there as well.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {

  "Value1": ["x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y"],

  "Value2": ["x", "z", "y", "y", "y", "x", "z", "y", "z", "y"],

  "Required output": [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.head()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['Period'] = df.Value1.ne(df.Value2).cumsum()
```

OUTPUT:
`

```
   Date and Time Value1 Value2  Required output  Period
0              1      x      x                1       0
1              2      x      z                2       1
2              3      y      y                2       1
3              4      y      y                2       1
4              5      y      y                2       1
5              6      x      x                2       1
6              7      x      z                3       2
7              8      y      y                3       2
8              9      y      z                4       3
9             10      y      y                4       3
```

If you want the period to start from 1 use:

```
df['Period'] = df.Value1.ne(df.Value2).cumsum() + 1
```

Comment: It can be very simple sometimes! Thanks!

Comment: You add ` + 1` or `add(1)` at the end to start at 1.

Comment: `df.Value1.ne(df.Value2).cumsum()+1`